# How to find files not tracked by git and then rsync those files?

Tags: git

My system is centos 7.

I use `git ls-files` to get files tracked by git.
And use `git lfs ls-files` to get files tracked by git-lfs.

But in my develop directory, has some folders  and files should not tracked by version control software,like `userdata`,`upload/avatar`.
Suppose stackoverflow is my site.User like you and me will upload avatar.These files often changed and should not tracked by git.

Those files are necessary when I deploy to production server,then I have thought:
Git has good function like `git clean -f -d`,but I don't want to delete just list those files.
 `rsync -aH not_tracked_files root@production server:/home/mywebsite`.

I don't know how to get `not_tracked_files` in rsync script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to find files not tracked by git

They need to be stored in another referential (other than your Git repository), and fetch during your deployment process (which involves rsync)

It can be a private Nexus server, it can be a private shared folder, a remote drive (onedrive/Google drive, AWS...), or even a vault, but it should not be your current Git repo.

The challenge is the version of not "not tracked by Git" files: if they don't change often, they can simply be statically stored once, and retrieve whenever you do your deployment.
If they change regularly, you need to track in your Git repo a reference to the right version of those files (a bit like lfs does for your large files, which are too stored elsewhere)

---

> Suppose stackoverflow is my site.User like you and me will upload avatar.These files often changed and should not tracked by git.

Those types of artifact are special in that you generally need only their latest version.
They can be managed in an independent referential. GitHub, for instance, manages its avatar through its own (historically) service [`gravatar.com`](https://en.gravatar.com/).

That means what you are deploying should be:

- reference to the avatar
- a program able to fetch, after deployment, the avatar from their referential and copy/update them on the production server if needed.

Comment: suppose stackoverflow is my site.User like you or me will upload avatar.These files often changed and should not tracked by git.But production server need avatar.

Comment: How to automatically list these avatar, that's the key.

Comment: @kittygirl avatar? You didn't not mention anything about the specific nature of the non-tracked files in your question. I will edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: I already revised question. It's my honor to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks! You point to a right way.But it's hard to implement because I run a small site.