# How to subtract folders and files list from another one?

Tags: bash, git

I have a git repo as below:

```
[root@localhost www]# tree
.
├── admin.php
├── api
    ├── index.htm
    └── remote
        └── mod
            ├── index.htm
            ├── mod_cron.php
            └── mod_index.php


3 directories, 5 files
```

It's easy to get the list of folder and files tracked by git.

```
[root@localhost www]# git ls-files >a.txt
[root@localhost www]# cat a.txt
.gitattributes
.gitignore
admin.php
api/index.htm
api/remote/mod/index.htm
api/remote/mod/mod_cron.php
api/remote/mod/mod_index.php
```

But in working direcotry, there's some folders and files not tracked by git.Whole working direcotry as below:

```
    [root@localhost www]# tree
    .
    ├── admin.php
    ├── api
    │   ├── index.htm
    │   └── remote
    │       ├── index.htm
    │       ├── index.php
    │       └── mod
    │           ├── index.htm
    │           ├── mod_cron.php
    │           └── mod_index.php
    ├── archiver
       └── index.php

4 directories, 8 files
```

**How to get the list of folders and files not tracked by git as below**:

```
archiver/
archiver/index.php
api/remote/index.htm
api/remote/index.php
```

I want to use this list in `rsync -av --files-from=/path/to/not_tracked_files_lsit`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: a `find` would give you a complete list of files present. `grep -vf a.txt` should eliminate the tracked files.

Comment: Another possible option: `git status -s|sed -n '/^[^?]/d; s/^?? //; p;'`

Comment: @PaulHodges,why not add answer

Comment: Just thought someone might offer a better one, but will do.

Comment: `git ls-files -o`?

Comment: See [Git: list only “untracked” files (also, custom commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3801321/4154375).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find files not tracked by git and then rsync those files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032723/how-to-find-files-not-tracked-by-git-and-then-rsync-those-files)

Comment: @jthill,cannot find empty folders not tracked by git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically copying in from comments above...

A `find` would give you a complete list of files present.

```
find | grep -v '[.]git/' | grep -vf a.txt
```

should eliminate the crap from the repo itself and all the tracked files.

Another option, probably better:

```
git status -s | sed -n '/^[^?]/d; s/^?? //; p;'
```

That should do much the same thing but hopefully a little cleaner and more to the point, with fewer processes in the pipeline.

Comment: If there's a empty folder not tracked by git,will be ignored by your script.

Comment: Only if empty - but you are right, an untracked empty folder will be ignored.